# tsc not creating the dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

All is in the title, trying to compile my TypeScript project to ./bin folder, the tsc commend execute without error resulting in nothing created, can't figure out why.

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "dom", "esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "bin",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "rootDirs": ["src/", "config/"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "./typings"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "bin", "**/__mocks__*", "**/*.spec.**", "test", "assets"]
}
```

In my package.json this is my scripts to compile:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
  },
```

the structure of my project:

```
rootdir
    |
    |-----src
    |      |----server.ts
    |      |----app.ts
    |-----test
    |-----node_modules
    |-----typings
    |-----config
    |-----tsconfig.json
    |-----package.json
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Starting with the most obvious: do you have permissions to create folders in that directory? Any errors in the shell? What happens when you run `tsc` directly at a prompt? Glancing over your config, it appears ok.

Comment: when i run the commend it execute without errors

Comment: You need to either remove `"noEmit": true` or pass `--noEmit false` in your `build-ts` script

Comment: @RemcoHaszing yes this is it :) thank you, if you write an answer i'll up vote

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `noEmit` option causes TypeScript to not emit any files. You need to either remove `"noEmit": true` or pass `--noEmit false` in your `build-ts` script.

Bonus tip: Rename the script to `prepack` to have `npm` compile the TypeScript for you when you run `npm pack` or `npm publish`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me too. I wonder how did it get there? I guess some package/script added it... regard to renaming, you mean literal replace "script" by "prepack" in the package.json? I'm also new to npm and react

Answer (score 76):

Another situation where TypeScript might not create a `dist` folder is when `"incremental": true` or `"composite": true` is set in `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`, and you delete the `dist` folder without deleting the `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` that keeps track of the incremental builds.

If you keep `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` around and delete or modify `dist`, the compiler won't see a need to output anything, since `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` is telling it that there's no work to do. The problem is the `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` references an old state of `dist`.

Say your `npm run clean` command runs `rimraf dist`. You'll have to update it to also `rimraf tsconfig.tsbuildinfo`.

Comment: In my case it was `"composite": true` setting, which implicitly sets `"incremental": true`.

Comment: OMG, I was the original poster of this question, 2 year letter, I get the same issue but with composite this time LOOL ...

Comment: I got it with tsconfig.tsbuildinfo when using rimraf dist && tsc. This saved me!

Comment: Finally solved it by deleting tsconfig.tsbuildinfo and then running tsc again. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `"outDir": "dist"` inside tsconfig.json isn't commented out or isn't referring to another path :)